# Wrapping custom notes in texreg output

Tags: r, latex, texreg

I'm trying to add a fairly long note to the bottom of a table created by `texreg`; I want this to simply wrap around, but there doesn't seem to be any functionality built into the function for doing so.

Take, e.g.:

```
texreg(
  lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars),
  custom.note = paste(
    "%stars. This regression should be",
    "intepreted with strong caution as",
    "it is likely plagued by extensive", 
    "omitted variable bias"
  )
)
```

Which, when compiled, gives something like:

[image: The complied TeX output of the regression; the footnote is all on one line, making the single-column result very wide and introducing lots of unnecessary white space]

The formatting is atrocious; much better would be something like replacing the standard output:

```
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$. This regression should be intepreted with strong caution as it is likely plagued by extensive omitted variable bias}}
```

With more digestible wrapping:

```
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$.}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{This regression should be intepreted with}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{strong caution as it is likely plagued by}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{extensive omitted variable bias}}
```

Which gives output much closer to what I'm looking for:

[image: Now, the footnote is wrapped -- the width of the footnote is dictated by the overall width of the table, rather than vice versa]

Is there a way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With version 1.37.1 (released in May 2020), `texreg` introduces the `threeparttable` argument, which uses the `threeparttable` LaTeX package, which was designed for this purpose.

Example R code:

```r
texreg(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars),
       custom.note = paste("\\item %stars. This regression",
                           "should be interpreted with strong",
                           "caution as it is likely plagued by",
                           "extensive omitted variable bias."),
       single.row = TRUE,
       threeparttable = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l c}
\hline
 & Model 1 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $8.28 \; (0.87)^{***}$ \\
dist        & $0.17 \; (0.02)^{***}$ \\
\hline
R$^2$       & $0.65$                 \\
Adj. R$^2$  & $0.64$                 \\
Num. obs.   & $50$                   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\scriptsize{\item $^{***}p<0.001$; $^{**}p<0.01$; $^{*}p<0.05$. This regression should be interpreted with strong caution as it is likely plagued by extensive omitted variable bias}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Which is rendered as:

[image: Screenshot of a single model]

Note that the custom note must start with `\\item`. It is also possible to have multiple items and/or use bullet points to format multiple notes like in a list:

```r
texreg(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars),
       custom.note = paste("\\item[$\\bullet$] %stars.",
                           "\\item[$\\bullet$] This regression",
                           "should be interpreted with strong",
                           "caution as it is likely plagued by",
                           "extensive omitted variable bias."),
       single.row = TRUE,
       threeparttable = TRUE)
```

The formatting is not perfect as you cannot set the desired width of the table; the note just adjusts to the width of the respective table. But I think it should be less of a problem in a realistic usage scenario where more than one model is displayed at a time and some of the coefficient names are longer than in the example. This solution also supports `longtable` environments, in which case the `threeparttablex` package is used instead.

Here is an example of how you could make it look nice with two models:

```r
fit <- lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
texreg(list(fit, fit),
       custom.note = paste("\\item[\\hspace{-5mm}] %stars.",
                           "\\item[\\hspace{-5mm}] This regression",
                           "should be interpreted with strong",
                           "caution as it is likely plagued by",
                           "extensive omitted variable bias."),
       single.row = TRUE,
       threeparttable = TRUE)
```

This yields:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l c c}
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $8.28 \; (0.87)^{***}$ & $8.28 \; (0.87)^{***}$ \\
dist        & $0.17 \; (0.02)^{***}$ & $0.17 \; (0.02)^{***}$ \\
\hline
R$^2$       & $0.65$                 & $0.65$                 \\
Adj. R$^2$  & $0.64$                 & $0.64$                 \\
Num. obs.   & $50$                   & $50$                   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\scriptsize{\item[\hspace{-5mm}] $^{***}p<0.001$; $^{**}p<0.01$; $^{*}p<0.05$. \item[\hspace{-5mm}] This regression should be interpreted with strong caution as it is likely plagued by extensive omitted variable bias.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Which renders as:

[image: Screenshot of two models]

Answer (score 4):

I might point out a neat [alternative solution I received](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797387/6574038) which could be of interest to you, at the latest when you need to update the texreg package.

Accordingly the custom note ends in a `\multicolumn` in the LaTeX code, thus we cannot use line break commands like `par` or `\\`. But we can achieve the automatic line break with `\parbox`. If we still want a custom line break we can use four backslashes `\\\\`. For better formatting we can use `\\vspace{2pt}` just at the beginning of the text content:

```
texreg(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars),
       custom.note = ("\\parbox{.4\\linewidth}{\\vspace{2pt}%stars. \\\\
       This regression should be intepreted with strong caution as it is 
       likely plagued by extensive omitted variable bias.}"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! I've been meaning to update my answer; indeed `parbox` is what I'm using myself these days!

Comment: To give the GOFs (here: the  R²) more space too we can add `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}` right before the `{r ...` chunk.

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with a workaround so far by rewriting the `texreg` function by adding a `custom.note.wrap` argument and changing:

```
note <- paste0("\\multicolumn{", length(models) + 1, 
               "}{l}{\\", notesize, "{", custom.note, "}}")
note <- gsub("%stars", snote, note, perl = TRUE)
```

To:

```
if (custom.note.wrap){
  note<-paste(paste0("\\multicolumn{", length(models) + 1L,"}{l}{\\",notesize,"{",
                     strwrap(custom.note, width=custom.note.wrap), "}}"),
              collapse = " \\ \n")
  note <- gsub("%stars", snote, note, perl = TRUE)
}else{
  note <- paste0("\\multicolumn{", length(models) + 1L, 
                 "}{l}{\\", notesize, "{", custom.note, "}}")
  note <- gsub("%stars", snote, note, perl = TRUE)
}
```

The idea is to pick a maximum string length for each line (`custom.note.wrap`) and then split the supplied note into strings of at most that length which end in a space, finally concatenating everything into a bunch of `multicolumn`s with each split substring.

This is not optimal, as it would be better for `texreg` (to have the ability) to automatically set `custom.note.wrap` given the lengths of the model names, etc. But my raw `LaTeX` abilities are lacking, so I'm not sure how I would do this.