# Adding multicolumns to my texreg output

Tags: r, texreg

I want to make a table with grouped *columns* via `texreg`. I can only see options for grouped *rows* (`groups`).

Here's an example:

```
set.seed(01349)
DF <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x1A = rnorm(100), x2A = rnorm(100),
                 x1B = rnorm(100), x2B = rnorm(100))
regs <- lapply(paste0("x", 1:2, c("A", "A", "B", "B")), function(x)
          lm(paste0("y ~ ", x), data = DF))
```

Here's as close as I can get with plain `texreg`:

```
texreg(regs, custom.coef.names = c("Intercept", rep("x", 4)),
       custom.model.names = c("1", "2", "1", "2"))
```

With LaTeX output:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c }
\hline
           & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
Intercept  & $-0.13$  & $-0.13$  & $-0.11$  & $-0.11$  \\
           & $(0.12)$ & $(0.12)$ & $(0.12)$ & $(0.12)$ \\
x          & $0.02$   & $0.07$   & $0.13$   & $-0.11$  \\
           & $(0.13)$ & $(0.12)$ & $(0.12)$ & $(0.13)$ \\
\hline
R$^2$      & 0.00     & 0.00     & 0.01     & 0.01     \\
Adj. R$^2$ & -0.01    & -0.01    & 0.00     & -0.00    \\
Num. obs.  & 100      & 100      & 100      & 100      \\
RMSE       & 1.18     & 1.17     & 1.17     & 1.17     \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I'd prefer an extra line (highlighted with `%` comments):

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c }
\hline
%*************A HEADER LINE HERE*********************
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\ %
%****************************************************
           & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
Intercept  & $-0.13$  & $-0.13$  & $-0.11$  & $-0.11$  \\
           & $(0.12)$ & $(0.12)$ & $(0.12)$ & $(0.12)$ \\
x          & $0.02$   & $0.07$   & $0.13$   & $-0.11$  \\
           & $(0.13)$ & $(0.12)$ & $(0.12)$ & $(0.13)$ \\
\hline
R$^2$      & 0.00     & 0.00     & 0.01     & 0.01     \\
Adj. R$^2$ & -0.01    & -0.01    & 0.00     & -0.00    \\
Num. obs.  & 100      & 100      & 100      & 100      \\
RMSE       & 1.18     & 1.17     & 1.17     & 1.17     \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\scriptsize{$^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Am I missing something, or is there no built-in way to do this?

My workaround is:

```
x <- capture.output(texreg(
  regs, custom.coef.names = c("Intercept", rep("x", 4)),
  custom.model.names = c("1", "2", "1", "2")))

x[6] <- paste0("& \\multicolumn{2}{c}{A} & \\multicolumn{2}{c}{B} \\\\ \n", x[6])

cat(x, sep = "\n")
```

But that's obviously a bit duct-tape-y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read code of the `function` by typing it into the console, or from the `github` [website](https://github.com/cran/texreg/blob/master/R/texreg.R) of the package `texreg`.

```
texreg
function (l, file = NULL, single.row = FALSE, stars = c(0.001, 
    0.01, 0.05), custom.model.names = NULL,...
```

This is the output of `texreg` for a table of 4 models:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c }
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4 \\
```

I looked into the code line [469](https://github.com/cran/texreg/blob/master/R/texreg.R#L469), the beginning of the table:

```
 string <- paste0(string, "\\begin{tabular}{", coldef, 
            "}", linesep)
```

Then I added some changes of my own:

```
string <- paste0(string, "\\begin{tabular}{", coldef, 
                 "}", linesep)
## Additions
string <- paste0(string, "\\\\[-1.8ex]\\hline", linesep)
string <- paste0(string, "& \\multicolumn{", length(l), 
                 "}{c}{\\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\\\", linesep)
string <- paste0(string, "\\cline{2-",length(modnames), "}", linesep)
string <- paste0(string, "\\\\[-1.8ex] & \\multicolumn{", length(l), 
                 "}{c}{", dep.var, "} \\\\", linesep)
```

Then, save the function with a different name for instance:

```
texreg2 <- function (l, file = NULL, single.row = FALSE, ...)
```

Now, the function requires internal functions from the package, so you need to attach your custom function to the namespace of the package in your environment. Easy peasy:

```
environment(texreg2) <- asNamespace('texreg')
```

Now you can call your new function. My additions include three lines and a name for the dependent variable, similar to `stargazer`.

```
texreg2(out, dep.var = "Normalize Citation Score")

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c }
\\[-1.8ex]\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\
\cline{2-5}
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Normalize Citation Score} \\
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 & Model 4 \\
```

Finally, if you don't like this method, you can manipulate the output with `regex`, checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902906/wrapping-custom-notes-in-texreg-output?rq=1) .

Comment: indeed this is how I have been going about adding `multicolumn`s for some time now. I find it's a bit too idiosyncratic to have bothered writing it up into a function, and just handle it case-by-case. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 6):

This may be late but still useful.

A new version of `texreg` (1.36.28) just came out on [GitHub](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg) (not on CRAN yet, May 22nd, 2020). It adds the option `custom.header` to create groups of regressions.

Applied to your example, it creates:

```
library(texreg)

set.seed(01349)
DF <- data.frame(y = rnorm(100), x1A = rnorm(100), x2A = rnorm(100),
                 x1B = rnorm(100), x2B = rnorm(100))
regs <- lapply(paste0("x", 1:2, c("A", "A", "B", "B")), function(x)
  lm(paste0("y ~ ", x), data = DF))

screenreg(
  regs, 
  custom.header = list("A" = 1:2, "B" = 3:4),
  custom.coef.names = c("Intercept", rep("x", 4)),
  custom.model.names = c("1", "2", "1", "2"),
)

=============================================
                   A                 B       
           ----------------  ----------------
           1        2        1        2      
---------------------------------------------
Intercept   -0.13    -0.13    -0.11    -0.11 
            (0.12)   (0.12)   (0.12)   (0.12)
x            0.02     0.07     0.13    -0.11 
            (0.13)   (0.12)   (0.12)   (0.13)
---------------------------------------------
R^2          0.00     0.00     0.01     0.01 
Adj. R^2    -0.01    -0.01     0.00    -0.00 
Num. obs.  100      100      100      100    
=============================================
*** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```

I used `screenreg()` to show the output more easily but it works with `texreg()` too.