# Table spacing issue converting to PDF via LaTeX with pandoc

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, texreg

I'm facing the issue that in R `texreg()` doesn't seem to break the lines in the notes below the table. Also the margins between the models are not extended equally like it's happening with `htmlreg()` which gives a clean result. Manual breaks like `\n` or HTML tags are not working with 'texreg'. There's a partly [workaround from MichaelChirico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902906/wrapping-custom-notes-in-texreg-output), but one has to change the `texreg()` function but it seems the method doesn't respect the case when we're dealing with more than one model side by side.

Here is the code I'm using:

````markdown
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "jaySf"
date: "13 Juni 2017"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r results="asis"}
library(car)
lm1 <- lm(prestige ~ income, data=Duncan)
lm2 <- lm(prestige ~ education, data=Duncan)
lm3 <- lm(prestige ~ income + education, data=Duncan)

library(texreg)
texreg(list(lm1, lm2, lm3), custom.note = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing 
       elitr, sed diam. %stars.") # for pdf output

htmlreg(list(lm1, lm2, lm3), custom.note = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing 
       elitr, sed diam. %stars.") # for html output
```
````

And this is the output:

[image: ugly table]

Does anybody have a clue? Any help is appreciated.

And here the LaTeX code which is produced:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true,
            pdftitle={Untitled},
            pdfauthor={jaySf},
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand{\VerbBar}{|}
\newcommand{\VERB}{\Verb[commandchars=\\\{\}]}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
% Add ',fontsize=\small' for more characters per line
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}
\newcommand{\KeywordTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\DataTypeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\BaseNTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\FloatTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ConstantTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\CharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\StringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\VerbatimStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\SpecialStringTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.31,0.60,0.02}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ImportTok}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\CommentTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\AnnotationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\CommentVarTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\OtherTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\FunctionTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\VariableTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ControlFlowTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.13,0.29,0.53}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\OperatorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.81,0.36,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\BuiltInTok}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\ExtensionTok}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\PreprocessorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textit{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\AttributeTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.77,0.63,0.00}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\RegionMarkerTok}[1]{{#1}}
\newcommand{\InformationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\WarningTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{{#1}}}}}
\newcommand{\AlertTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.94,0.16,0.16}{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\ErrorTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.64,0.00,0.00}{\textbf{{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\NormalTok}[1]{{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

%%% Use protect on footnotes to avoid problems with footnotes in titles
\let\rmarkdownfootnote\footnote%
\def\footnote{\protect\rmarkdownfootnote}

%%% Change title format to be more compact
\usepackage{titling}

% Create subtitle command for use in maketitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{
  \posttitle{
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    }
}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}
  \title{Untitled}
  \pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}\centering\huge}
  \posttitle{\par}
  \author{jaySf}
  \preauthor{\centering\large\emph}
  \postauthor{\par}
  \predate{\centering\large\emph}
  \postdate{\par}
  \date{13 Juni 2017}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(car)}
\NormalTok{lm1 <-}\StringTok{ }\KeywordTok{lm}\NormalTok{(prestige ~}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{income, }\DataTypeTok{data=}\NormalTok{Duncan)}
\NormalTok{lm2 <-}\StringTok{ }\KeywordTok{lm}\NormalTok{(prestige ~}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{education, }\DataTypeTok{data=}\NormalTok{Duncan)}
\NormalTok{lm3 <-}\StringTok{ }\KeywordTok{lm}\NormalTok{(prestige ~}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{income +}\StringTok{ }\NormalTok{education, }\DataTypeTok{data=}\NormalTok{Duncan)}

\KeywordTok{library}\NormalTok{(texreg)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{verbatim}
## Version:  1.36.23
## Date:     2017-03-03
## Author:   Philip Leifeld (University of Glasgow)
## 
## Please cite the JSS article in your publications -- see citation("texreg").
\end{verbatim}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{texreg}\NormalTok{(}\KeywordTok{list}\NormalTok{(lm1, lm2, lm3), }\DataTypeTok{custom.note =} \StringTok{"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing }
\StringTok{       elitr, sed diam. %stars."}\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c }
\hline
 & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $2.46$       & $0.28$       & $-6.06$      \\
            & $(5.19)$     & $(5.09)$     & $(4.27)$     \\
income      & $1.08^{***}$ &              & $0.60^{***}$ \\
            & $(0.11)$     &              & $(0.12)$     \\
education   &              & $0.90^{***}$ & $0.55^{***}$ \\
            &              & $(0.08)$     & $(0.10)$     \\
\hline
R$^2$       & 0.70         & 0.73         & 0.83         \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.69         & 0.72         & 0.82         \\
Num. obs.   & 45           & 45           & 45           \\
RMSE        & 17.40        & 16.69        & 13.37        \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\scriptsize{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing 
       elitr, sed diam. $^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$.}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{htmlreg}\NormalTok{(}\KeywordTok{list}\NormalTok{(lm1, lm2, lm3), }\DataTypeTok{custom.note =} \StringTok{"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>consetetur sadipscing }
\StringTok{       elitr, sed diam. %stars."}\NormalTok{)}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

Statistical models

Model 1

Model 2

Model 3

(Intercept)

2.46

0.28

-6.06

(5.19)

(5.09)

(4.27)

income

1.08***

0.60***

(0.11)

(0.12)

education

0.90***

0.55***

(0.08)

(0.10)

R2

0.70

0.73

0.83

Adj. R2

0.69

0.72

0.82

Num. obs.

45

45

45

RMSE

17.40

16.69

13.37

{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam.
\emph{\textbf{p \textless{} 0.001, }p \textless{} 0.01, }p \textless{}
0.05.}


\end{document}
```

Comment: In addition to the solution you posted, see also the new `threeparttable` argument in `texreg`. It's described in my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902906/wrapping-custom-notes-in-texreg-output/62439440#62439440.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I gladly quote the great [answer I received from Fran at https://tex.stackexchange.com/](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376952/136969).

According to him the custom note ends in a `\multicolumn` in the LaTeX code. Thus we cannot use line break commands like `par` or `\\`. But we can achieve the automatic line break with `\parbox`. If we still want a custom line break we can use four backslashes `\\\\`. For better formatting we use `\\vspace{2pt}`. To give even the Coefficients and the GOFs more space we can add `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}` (default is 1) right before the R chunk:

````
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}  

```{r results="asis", echo = TRUE, comment = FALSE, message = FALSE}

library(texreg)
texreg(list(lm1, lm2, lm3), custom.note = "\\parbox{.4\\linewidth}
{\\vspace{2pt}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliquyam. \\\\ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliquyam. \\\\ %stars.}")

```
````

[image]

Comment: Saved me a lot of trouble. Excellent answer, thank you. (I ended up using `1.5`.)